# Redshift is same as Doppler effect in sound ? if not how different it is?

Tags: doppler-effect, redshift

Is redshift same as doppler effect in sound ? if not what makes it different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Doppler effect in sound results from the motion of the source or observer relative to the air. A red shift (in the vacuum of space) results from the motion of the source and observer relative to each other (which may relate to the expansion of space).  A red shift can also be a result of a gravitational time dilation.